# Cannot write a string in bidirectional language. Seems like Mission impossible

Tags: unicode, bidi

I have the following string:

```
א 2  1 ב
```

2 R2L characters (Hebrew or Arabic) with 2 digits in the middle. All characters separated by spaces.

Now I need to insert between the 2 digits an English character, let's say an uppercase 'X'. Anything I try shuffles the string. How do I type these sequence of characters without messing up this string ?

Comment: and the award for most overly dramatic question title goes to…

Comment: to be helpful, though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark

Comment: I didn't post this question as a riddle. It's a problem we are facing in a project to convert data from a legacy system to a new environment. Before the bi-directional era, the characters of the R2L languages replaced the lowercase English characters in the ASCI table and there wasn't any bi-di algorithms. In the legendary VT terminals we used escape commands to switch between cursor directions. The strings looked visually right. We are now working on a tool that convert these complex strings to look visually as they looked identically in the legacy DB.

Comment: In essence, the RTL and LTR marks do pretty much the same as your escaped characters; so maybe you want to show the unicode point sequences you know that don't work – I'm not quite sure that there's "left to right characters", I just assume that the renderer sees a Hebrew unicode code point and thinks "let's switch to RTL", or something like that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in code? In what programming language/platform/OS? Or are you trying to do it manually? In what text editor?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing a function to translate strings from a so-called "Old-code 7-bit Hebrew" to "Windows-1255" Hebrew. The programming language we use is MUMPS under a Linux platform. The old Hebrew is visual with no bidi feature. The function must transform the string to the right sequence in order to look exactly in the windows (or UTF) environment as in the old one. The example above is simplified but the real strings are a lot more complex and even very hard to type manually.

Comment: Sidney. I have done my fair bit of bidi in Arabic while on a VistA project. It seems to me that your renderer (putty?) is switching characters around. Use a hex dumper to see what's actually stored (or in M, the zwrite command). I wrote a few blog posts on the topic. Google my name and UTF-8.

Comment: Hi Sam. Thanks for your comment. Do you have a MUMPS Routine or function that converts visual RTL (Arabic) strings to logical strings. In other words a function that implement the bidi algorithm in M?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem that works with all digits and all RTL characters is to use a LTR mark as indicated in [this answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1236108/23433).

So your string would need the characters:

> [U+05D4](http://graphemica.com/%D7%94)
>
> [U+200E](https://graphemica.com/200E)
>
> U+0020 (simple space)
>
> U+0031 (simple 1)
>
> U+0020 (simple space)
>
> U+00XX (any normal ASCII letter)
>
> U+0020 (simple space)
>
> U+0032 (simple 2)
>
> U+0020 (simple space)
>
> [U+05D0](http://graphemica.com/%D7%90) (or the Math Aleph if you rather)

You only need to add the LTR mark in places where there are characters following a RTL (Hebrew or Arabic) letter.